# View of content in parent component from child component using anchor tag 'href' in angular4?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Here, I am trying to separately create  `tab.component.ts` and kept content of id="tab-1" ... in parent.component.ts. But, getting error

1) Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Here, I have referred code from the plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/wflXtbu8d7vvU4puH8hc?p=preview   and modified as I have created a separate tab.component.ts.

Please, help finding the solution? 
Here, is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bdf9VROBedE5ph0l6qlj?p=preview

```
  parent.component.ts
     ---------------------
@Component({
------------
})
     import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

        export class parentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  name: string;
  tabsdata = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  @ViewChild('child') child: TabComponent;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'simple tabs';
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.child.activeTab('tab-1');
  }
}
        parent.component.html
        ------------------------
<div class="col-xs-12 rmpm">
    <div class="tabs tabsMenu" #tabs>

        <app-tab [tabsdata]='tabsdata'></app-tab>

        <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content" role="tabpanel">
            1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </div>
        <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content" role="tabpanel">
            2 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
        <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content" role="tabpanel">
            3 Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud execitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </div>
        <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content" role="tabpanel">
            4 Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        tab.component.html
        ------------------------
     <ul class=" nav nav-tabs " role="tablist">
    <li class="tab-link" *ngFor="let tab of tabsdata;let i = index;" [ngStyle]="{'width': 'calc(100% /' + tabsdata.length + ')'}">
        <a (click)="tabsUL($event)" href="#tab-{{i+1}}" role="tab">{{tab}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
        tab.component.ts
        ------------------------
import { Component, OnInit, Input, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab',
  templateUrl: './tab.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab.component.css']
})
export class TabComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  name: string;
  id = 'tab-1';
  @Input() tabsdata: any;
  @ViewChild('tabs') private tabs;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'simple tabs';
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.activeTab('tab-1');
  }

  tabsUL(event): void {
    const tab_id = event.target.hash.replace('#', '');
    this.activeTab(tab_id);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  activeTab(id) {
    const tabsEl = this.tabs.nativeElement;
    this.removeActive(tabsEl.querySelectorAll('.active'));
    this.setActive([
      tabsEl.querySelector(`#${id}`),
      tabsEl.querySelector(`[href="#${id}"]`).parentNode
    ]);

  }

  setActive(elems) {
    elems.forEach((el) => {
      el.className += ' active';
    });
  }

  removeActive(elems) {
    elems.forEach((el) => {
      el.className = el.className.replace(' active', '');
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things that don't look right,

```
@ViewChild('tabs') private tabs;
```

The ViewChild decorator parameter should be either a component name or an id in the template. In the plunker, there is

```
<div class="tabs" #tabs>
```

which is why it works there.

Also, tab.component.ts has fundamental errors, like not using @Component.

Did you reference the wrong Plunker? None of the code above is shown there.

Comment: Updated code...above...

<div class="col-xs-12 rmpm">
    <div class="tabs tabsMenu" #tabs>...............it is in   parent.component.html

Comment: Here, is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WTEiNsdjcfkzpGSgVcKo?p=preview

Comment: Perhaps the error is in tab.component.ts --
  activeTab(id) {
    const tabsEl = this.tabs.nativeElement;
    this.removeActive(tabsEl.querySelectorAll('.active'));
    this.setActive([
      tabsEl.querySelector(`#${id}`),
      tabsEl.querySelector(`[href="#${id}"]`).parentNode
    ]);

  }

  setActive(elems) {
    elems.forEach((el) => {
      el.className += ' active';
    });
  }

  removeActive(elems) {
    elems.forEach((el) => {
      el.className = el.className.replace(' active', '');
    });
  }

Comment: No, the reference plunker is correct. What, I have done is just created a tab.component.ts and and passed it as selector in parent.component.ts.